# How to remove file from cache directory in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am working in a camera app where I can record video and save that in the directory like this:

```
file:///var/mobile/Applications/2683FFEC-63AB-4004-831B-DE38053CA472/Library/Caches/0C2E7E7C-5D78-4989-9C8E-259B3595BAC8-6498-0000042F24AB2D98.mov
```

when I go to the camera application I can see the video, but I want to delete this video when I quit the app, I did this so far

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:THEABOVEURL error:&error];
```

but nothing happens and says `cocoa error 4.The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory`

But I am sure that the file exists as I can play the video using the exact url mentioned above, what should I do now?

Comment: What u get in error object?

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa Error 4 means

`NSFileNoSuchFileError = 4, // Attempt to do a file system operation on a non-existent file`

so it looks like that file just doesn't exist.

You may want to be sure that the file exists when you're going to delete it, maybe there is something wrong in the url that you are using?

```
- (BOOL)removeItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

it takes a string as first parameter, I see on your code

```
[vedioPaths objectAtIndex:THEABOVEURL]
```

it looks like THEABOVEURL should be an index, and vedioPaths contains all the NSString representing the path of the files, Add some NSLog to see if these variables contain the right information to delete the file.

Comment: Sorry I miss typed the code, please see my edited code, thanks and I am pretty sure about the file existance As I can play that video before deleting it with the same url

Comment: I see that my video file is being saved in the cache memory, is there any read write permission issue in cache memory?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it my way, I was trying to delete an url where the

```
- (BOOL)removeItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

method wants NSUrl as parameter I converted this string as url and used this method

```
NSURL *urlfromString= [NSURL URLWithString:ABOVEURL];
[fileManager removeItemAtURL:urlfromString error:&error];
```

This solved my problem